# Add to dictionary by value (and generate key)

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables, dictionary

In Django, you often have to add many variables into dictionary (context in views). Names of these variables are often big to be clear what it is.

Example:

```
userprofile_creation_form = UserProfileCreationForm()
```

It's uncomfortable, when you have a lot of such variables, to write keys for them since keys are often the same as variable names.

```
context['userprofile_creation_form'] = userprofile_creation_form
... imagine 6 other variables
... 
...
```

So I would like to be able to put variable into dictionary just using this variable and name would be generated from it's name.

Like:

```
context.add(userprofile_creation_form)

>>> context 
>>> {'userprofile_creation_form':<Form userprofile_creation_form>, ... }
```

Is it possible to do that somehow in python or is there some module or workaround which can provide this behaviour?

Comment: @DavidZ I think this is not an exact duplicate. The question you assigned asks about extracting name from a variable which can be a part of my solution but there are more possible answers. For example, maybe there exists such module (like OrderedDict, DefaultDict etc. ) which can provide this behaviour.

Comment: It sounds like you missed the other half of the question, which asks about the reverse operation, putting variables into a dictionary using the names of the variables as keys. That's _exactly_ what you're asking about.

Answer (score 0):

In the following example, `form.__class__.__name__` gives the name of form class:

```
for form in my_forms:
    k = ''.join('_{}'.format(c.lower()) if c.isupper() else c for c in form.__class__.__name__).lstrip('_')
    context[k] = form
```

**Example:**

```
>>> class MyForm1:
...     pass
...
>>> class MyForm2:
...     pass
...
>>>
>>> my_forms = [MyForm1(), MyForm2()]
>>>
>>> context = {}
>>>
>>> for form in my_forms:
...     k = ''.join('_{}'.format(c.lower()) if c.isupper() else c for c in form.__class__.__name__).lstrip('_')
...     context[k] = form
...
>>> context
{'my_form1': <__main__.MyForm1 instance at 0x0000000002653188>, 'my_form2': <__main__.MyForm2 instance at 0x0000000002653548>}
>>>
```

If you want to add your forms to `context` with the exact name, use:

```
>>> for form in my_forms:
...     context[form.__class__.__name__] = form
...
>>> context
{'MyForm2': <__main__.MyForm2 instance at 0x0000000002713548>, 'MyForm1': <__main__.MyForm1 instance at 0x0000000002713188>}
```